# abp.io - abp suite error when pressing Modules menu item

Tags: abp

ABP Framework version: 6.0.0-rc.5
UI type: MVC
DB provider: EF Core
Tiered (MVC) or Identity Server Separated (Angular): yes

Exception message and stack trace:
[22:49:36 ERR] Error occured while getting the versions from https://api.github.com/repos/abpframework/abp/releases -- Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'Volo.Abp.Cli.ProjectBuilding.AbpIoSourceCodeStore+GithubReleaseVersions' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.
Path '', line 1, position 1.

Note: This is the latest preview: Version 6.0.0-rc.5
Version 6.0.0-rc.4 works fine

Steps to reproduce the issue:

abp suite

Create a new solution:

Application template, Tiered with Public web site

Press Modules... Empty page displays

[image]

Answer (score 0):

this is an issue on `6.0.0-rc.5` and we have addressed the issue. the problem will be fixed with the next (stable) release in this week.